# QProcess doesn't terminate the program

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qtcore

```
QProcess pro;
pro.start("Notepad");
QTimer::singleShot(3000, &pro, &QProcess::terminate);
```

After 3 seconds it must terminate my notepad.exe but it won't I have no idea what's the problem

I changed it with (kill) but it still won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design (OS-dependant) running a command without full path is an equivalent of `system` function in POSIX and, by its implementation it doesn't have this granularity of control on created processes, because there was a shell process between your application and one you meant to execute. As `notepad.exe` is a GUI application, it immediately returns control to shell, which is terminated afterward, a Windows-specific behaviour of program's stub code. For all purposes your `QProcess` is already stopped.

Qt had in past special behaviour for Windows, where command are passed to `cmd.exe`. The rules regarding to running, passing arguments to and terminating processes change from program to program, most notable would be `cmd.exe` itself. Behaviour still vary with newfangled `startCommand` member function.

You have to either find the true location of notepad.exe, e.g. via [`QStandardPaths::locate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstandardpaths.html) (introduced in Qt 5.0) or ask user to configure it.